# how to deploy React App with links in iis server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React App with multiple links in it.

When i deploy in server first it is working fine , when i refresh the page it is throwing : "404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. "  error.

I have added .htaccess file and tried still same

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

this solved same problem on my apache server: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourwebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```